# Highlighting text in a document from a set that has multi word elements?

Tags: python, string, text, split, highlight

I need to highlight some text in large documents based on a set of keywords. Seems pretty straightforward, split the text by spaces and check if in list. The issue is that some keywords in the list are multiple words. See my simplified code below

```
from termcolor import cprint

text = "I enjoy Virtual Reality games"
keywords = ["virtual", "virtual reality"]

for word in text.split(" "):
    if word.lower() in keywords:
        cprint(word, "red", end=" ")
    else:
        print(word, end=" ")
```

Obviously, only 'Virtual' will be highlighted with this approach. I could always go with brute force permutations, but that is going to be incredibly inefficient. What is the best way to go about this (and keeping in mind that a set element can have more than 2 words in it)? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `re` module and `re.split`:

```py
import re
from termcolor import cprint

text = "I enjoy Virtual Reality games"
keywords = {"virtual", "virtual reality"}  # <-- make it set

pat = re.compile(
    r"\b("
    + "|".join(map(re.escape, sorted(keywords, key=len, reverse=True)))
    + r")\b",
    flags=re.I,
)

for w in map(str.strip, pat.split(text)):
    if w.lower() in keywords:
        cprint(w, "red", end=" ")
    else:
        print(w, end=" ")

print()
```

Prints (screenshot from gnome terminal):

[image]

---

EDIT: Added `\b` to both sides of regex.

Comment: This is great. Didn't even think of using regex. Thanks so much

Comment: How do I get it such that the regex doesn't match for substrings of a word? For example, if you add "capital" to the end of the text and "api" to the keyword set, the substring "api" that is in "capital" will still be highlighted in the output, which I do not want

Comment: @almosthavoc Try to change regex - add `\b` to both sides = `r"\b(" + ... + r")\b"`. See my edit.